# Add strings in R and convert to numeric

Tags: r

I need to convert this vector of strings:

```
v <- c("60","40 60","30","NA")
```

To this vector by summing each occurrence

```
60 100 30 NA
```

is there an easy way to do this in a vector without looping over each instance?

Comment: `sapply(strsplit(v, " "), function(x) sum(as.numeric(x)))`

Comment: Please write functional code, not pseudocode.

Comment: Updated and thanks d.b works great

Answer (score 2):

Because each element of the vector may contain multiple values, you are stuck using list functions. Use lapply to strsplit and convert to numeric before iterating over *that* list with a sum function. Toggle na.rm to handle NA values differently.

```
v <- c("60","40 60","30","NA")
sapply(lapply(strsplit(v, " "), as.numeric), sum, na.rm=F)
```